# LEFT JOIN and IS NULL working but not the SUM function

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, isnull

I perform the sub query to identify the rows that I want to ***exclude***. Those are the ones that have NULL values on column b.`Parent Supplier Name`. That works fine until I try to get the sum( b.`Spend Value in LC` ) for the rest.

```
SELECT a.`BW Parent Number` , a.`Vendor Name` , b.`Parent Supplier Name` , sum( b.`Spend Value in LC` ) as sum
FROM scrubs a
LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT `Child Supplier ID` , `Parent Supplier Name` , `Spend Value in LC` 
    FROM pdwspend
    WHERE `BU ID` = 'BU_1'
    AND `version` LIKE '%FINAL%'
 )b ON a.`BW Parent Number` = b.`Child Supplier ID` 

WHERE a.`year` =2014
AND b.`Parent Supplier Name` IS NULL 
GROUP BY a.`BW Parent Number` 
ORDER BY sum( b.`Spend Value in LC` ) DESC
```

The result desire has this structure:

```
`BW Parent Number` | `Vendor Name` | `Parent Supplier Name` | sum
 BW0001               XYC                 NULL                300,000
 .....
 .....
```

Right now I get this for all the rows that **are not included** in the sub query:

```
`BW Parent Number` | `Vendor Name` | `Parent Supplier Name` | sum
 BW0001               XYC                 NULL                NULL
 ....
 ....
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show some example data.

Comment: You can try doing `Sum(Coalesce(b.\`Spend Value in LC\`, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Like so many others before you, you have fallen prey to mysql's non-standard grouping support...

**Ensure all non-aggregated columns are listed in the `group by` clause:**

```
...
GROUP BY a.`BW Parent Number`, a.`Vendor Name`
...
```

While other databases would rause an SQL exception if you tried you query, Mysql allows you to omit non-aggregated colums, in which case it returns a *single random row* (as a matter of practicality, it returns the *first* row) for each unique group as coded.

Comment: Thanks for the replied. I have tried `GROUP BY a.`BW Parent Number`, a.`Vendor Name` ;  and also ;  ``GROUP BY a.`BW Parent Number`, a.`Vendor Name` , b.`Parent Supplier Name` , b.`Child Supplier ID``, without sucess. I know that these rows have actual values on b.`Spend Value in LC`. Any advise?